# ¿Cuantos dias tengo para determinado mes? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data

Tengo este dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito saber el total de dias por cada mes del cual tengo informacion, es decir para el mes de mayo tengo data de 10 dias (del 2 al 12 por ejemplo).

¿Como obtengo este resultado?

```
|mes|total_dias|
 ______________
|May|20        |
 ______________
|Jun|30        |
```

Entiendo que debo agrupar por mes, luego de eso agrupar por dia y luego contar

```
df.groupby(["mes","dia"]).count()
```

Sin embargo el resultado no es el esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas es obtener el número de días transcurridos entre el primer y ultimo día registrado para cada mes. Entonces, la función `count()` no sirve, porque cuenta cuantos registros hay, no cual es el rango de días que cubre.

La solución consiste en agrupar las filas por mes usando `groupby()`, que retorna un iterable. En este caso, cada elemento del iterable es una tupla de dos elementos:

- El nombre del mes.
- Un dataframe con las filas del mes.

Tupla:

```
('Junio',      mes  dia
5  Junio    1
6  Junio    2
7  Junio    2
8  Junio    3
9  Junio    4)
('Mayo',     mes  dia
0  Mayo   25
1  Mayo   25
2  Mayo   26
3  Mayo   26
4  Mayo   26)
```

Con esta información podemos determinar el primer y último día del mes usando `min()` y `max()` sobre su correspondiente dataframe. Con eso podemos calcular el número de días.

La información la recolectamos en una lista de [mes, dias]. Cuando lka hayamos completado, construimos un dataframe con los resultados.

Eso sería todo.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datos = [
    ["Mayo", 25],
    ["Mayo", 25],
    ["Mayo", 26],
    ["Mayo", 26],
    ["Mayo", 26],
    ["Junio", 1],
    ["Junio", 2],
    ["Junio", 2],
    ["Junio", 3],
    ["Junio", 4],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["mes", "dia"])
print("Datos")
print(df)

res = []
for x in df.groupby(["mes"]):
    mes = x[0]
    dic = x[1]
    dias = dic['dia'].max() - dic['dia'].min() + 1
    res.append([mes, dias])

af = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["mes", "dias"])
print("Totales")
print(af)
```

produce

```
Datos
     mes  dia
0   Mayo   25
1   Mayo   25
2   Mayo   26
3   Mayo   26
4   Mayo   26
5  Junio    1
6  Junio    2
7  Junio    2
8  Junio    3
9  Junio    4
Totales
     mes  dias
0  Junio     4
1   Mayo     2
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias! un abrazo.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer algo sencillo.

Primero, agrupas el dataframe por mes y almacenas en una variable "grouped_data_month":

```
    grouped_data_month = df.groupby(["mes"])
```

Seguido, haces una lista con los meses que efectivamente registraron alguna medición:

```
months = pd.unique(df.mes)
```

Después, obtienes el número de mediciones al mes y creas un nuevo data frame con la información:

```
result_list = []
for month in months:
    tmp_data = grouped_data_month.get_group(month).copy()
    result_list.append([month, len(tmp_data)])

final_data = pd.DataFrame(result_list, columns=['Mes', '´Número de registros'])
```

4. Muestras el resultado:

Si estas trabajando en un notebook basta con que escribas el nombre del data frame final

```
final_data
```